# Flutter & provider: How can I change texts by int value of the provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

If the type of change notifier is bool, I could just change text like this:

```
...
Consumer<LoginOrSignup>(
  builder: (context, value, child) =>
      Text(value.isSignup? "Sign up" : "Login")
)
...
```

LoginorSignup.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LoginOrSignup extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isSignup = false;

  bool get isSignup => _isSignup;
}
```

If *_isSignup* type is int, how can I change the text?

++Update: I remember writing this like 2 years ago. I didn't understand how flutter works and how the package `provider` works, and the main point of the question is not even related to `provider`. I honestly have no idea what I was tryna ask, but if I try translating it, I think I was tryna say like how to do `child: variableThatIsAnInt == 0 ? Text("Hii") : Text("Idk whatever")`. I definitely have no idea who upvoted this crazily confusing question, but thank you.

Comment: not sure I understand the question - they all bool. conversion can be done with the parse method `bool.parse` I guess. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you should add method to your **LoginOrSignup** class, then call this method when you want, like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LoginOrSignup extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isSignup = false;

  bool get isSignup => _isSignup;

  void changeStatus(bool status){
    _isSignup = status;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

in your view call

```dart
value.changeStatus(false); //or true
```